# Installshield, how to verify internet connection before installation?

Tags: installshield

I am using Installshield for the installation of a product.

I am attempting to find a way to verify an active internet connection before I continue with the installation of my product.

I checked all over, even the manual/help guides from the Installshield people.

I am setting "Program Features" through the Installation Designer->Setup Design->Program Feature(s), and figure if anyplace, it would be in here.

Has anyone worked on this before, and found a viable solution?

ps: I am also trying to find a way to check for minimum system requirements as well (NOT THE O.S. Version, just simple things such as minimum physical memory and minimum RAM)

Much Appreciated,
-Kyle

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I wouldn't do it in an install, I would do it in the application as the state of the internet connection could change after the install is performed.

I'd also want to clearly understand why this is required before implementing it.  For example I have no direct internet access ( by design ) where I do my software development for security purposes.   If I couldn't install or run software because of that, I simply wouldn't buy the software.

Then there are security implications of software applications and installs phoning home and hence why I stay disconnected from the internet on certain machines.

That said, to test for an internet connection, you first have to define what that means.  Perhaps you have a public web service that you want to invoke?

Comment: The internet connection is needed for the purpose of downloading the latest version of various programs, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader, etc. I could do it in the application I suppose. I thought it would be nice to package it up within the install. ps: I am still at a loss of why you would develop without an internet connection... for example, what if you have a question you need to ask on a certain website (stackoverflow). Thanks, I'll go from here.

Comment: We have very stringent security and configuration management requirements. The only way to make sure you aren't being hacked and spied on or that employees aren't using inapproriate software or orse stealing IP is to pull the plug and create an airgap. I have an internet facing terminal that is locked down ( no Admin perms ) that I can do my surfing and googling on. But any thing I download that I need to do my job must go through security and configuration management to make it into our development environment.  Anything leaving our environment must do the same.